# how to resize image without changing DPI in opencv for detecting text and feeding into OCR?

Tags: text, opencv, ocr, image

i resized the image using open cv and it changed the dpi of the image from 300 dpi to 90 dpi . What is the correct way to resize image without changing its dpi in open cv . if we feed the resized image of 90 dpi  into OCR it barley recognizes any text in the image .